# How to get a String from a variable depth in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-statements

i'm trying to get a string from a nested object, basically it's really simple.
a server returns an error-code with a varying amount of `-`-delimited strings (2-4)
now basically what i want to do is

```
 return `${messageStrings[errorCodeParts[0]]
  [errorCodeParts[1]]
  [errorCodeParts[2]]
  [errorCodeParts[3]]}`
```

but only as far down as needed... (so 2 parts, do until `errorCodeParts[1]`, 3 parts, do until `errorCodeParts[2]`. i don't know how to do this elegantly, can anyone point me in a direction?

this is the current code:

```
const messageStrings = {
  auth: {
    failed: 'These credentials do not match our records.',
    throttle: 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.',
  }
// ..
}

  getString(errorCode) {    // errorCode = 'auth-failed'
    const errorCodeParts = Array.from(errorCode.split('-'))

    let string = 'Unknown error'

        return `${messageStrings[errorCodeParts[0]]
  [errorCodeParts[1]]
  [errorCodeParts[2]]
  [errorCodeParts[3]]}` // but only those that are actually there
  }
```

Comment: Your string is delimited by dashes not dots, but I think the duplicate is the pointer in the right direction you were looking for :-)

Comment: ohh ok, gonna read that. thanks!

Comment: whoa, it works! i'm not sure i understand it, but it works :D thanks man!

Comment: The dupe is a good start, but the `10` in your example `username-length-max-10` will need some extra handling.